# How to use @Query in URL in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

Hi all i call below **URL** using `Retrofit`

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?key=gQJsL7krOvbXkJ0NEI((&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token=HM*22z8nkaaoyjA8))&filter=default
```

and for that i created `Interface RestInterface`

```
 //get UserId
 @GET("/me&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token={access_token}&filter=default")
 void getUserId(@Query("key") String apikey,@Path("access_token") String access_token,Callback<UserShortInfo> cb);
```

When i do this it always add key at the end of the `URL(Output below)`.

I added **@Query("key")** as `Query Parameter` becoz it's dynamic.

```
 http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token=p0j3dWLIcYQCycUHPdrA%29%29&filter=default?key=gQJsL7krOvbXkJ0NEI%28%28
```

and that's the wrong. I got `HTTP 400`. Also here `((` and  `))` converted into `%28%28`  and `%29%29`

Please help me how to make

```
 https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?key=gQJsL7krOvbXkJ0NEI((&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token=HM*22z8nkaaoyjA8))&filter=default
```

in `Retrofit`. I want it add `@Query` parameter in between `URL`. not at the end of the `URL`

Comment: Are you sure your key is correct? I get a 'key doesn't match an application' error, when I access the url.

Comment: @gauravjain Actually i changed the `Key` for Security purpose. I just want to find a way how to add `@Query` in between `URL`. not at the end

Comment: @Selvin Thanx budy for your call but in `URL` `?key`. main problem is i want to make URL like `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?key=gQJsL7krOvbXkJ0NEI((&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token=HM*22z8nkaaoyjA8))&filter=default`

Comment: I think that the problem is `/me&` instead `/me?` in your url ... try to change it ... and then use `@Query` ... this also should help

Comment: @Selvin by using `@Query` it added key in `URL` but at the end. I want to add in between so my final `URL` seems like  `me?key=gQJsL7krOvbXkJ0NEI((&site.......`

Comment: and? the order doesn't matter

Comment: @Selvin You're right but when i called URL with that it give me 400 error: it's not working

Comment: when I call it is working ... what did you change ? did you tried /me& instead /me? or &key={key} ? or nothing and you still dont get that order doesn't matter and changing ) to %29 doesn't matter

Comment: @Selvin let me try and also it's convert `((` to `%29%29`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97854/discussion-between-m-d-and-selvin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously instead

```
@GET("/me&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token={access_token}&filter=default")
void getUserId(@Query("key") String apikey,@Path("access_token") String access_token,Callback<UserShortInfo> cb);
```

you should use

```
@GET("/me?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default")
void getUserId(@Query("key") String apikey,@Query("access_token") String access_token,Callback<UserShortInfo> cb);
```

the chanege is `/me&` to `/me?` ... (and second is to use `access_token` as `Query` param too, not as a `Path`)

**edit** more explanations:

After parsing url which looks like (`me&`)

```
scheme:host/me&blablalbal=blalbla&blabla=blabla
```

the path is

```
me&blablalbal=blalbla&blabla=blabla
```

and there is no query paramas at all ... so adding params end with adding `?param=value` at the end

but with (`me?`)

```
scheme:host/me?blablalbal=blalbla&blabla=blabla
```

the path is

```
me
```

and there are already some query parameters ... so addin new end with adding `&param=value` at the end :)

Comment: Let me try this out. The correct one is [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?key=gQJsL7krOvbXkJ0NEI*mWA((&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token=HM*22z8nkaaoyjA8PDj2Pg))&filter=default)

Comment: again: The order of url paramas doesn't matter ... this will produce the correct url ..

Answer (score 1):

Don't put query parameter inside the URL only the path parameter you can add

```
@GET("/me?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default)
void getUserId(@Query("key") String apikey,@Query("access_token") String access_token,Callback<UserShortInfo> cb);

@Query("access_token") --> given key and value will come query URL
```

While sending request your URL form will like below

```
/me?key=?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default&"your_value"&access_token="your_value"
```